# Need Help Understanding Function that Removes Duplicates in Array and Sums up values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reduce

So I'm fairly new to Javascript and I was working through the FCC curriculum when I came across an excercise that required me to take a multi-dimensional array, and combine duplicate items while summing up their values.

After searching around on the web (Stackoverflow nonetheless) I came across the code snippet below that accomplishes just that. The only problem is that I don't completely understand what is going on in the nested "if" statement when the logic evaluates "true".

I understand all other parts of the code just fine, but that if statement is just throwing me off.

Anyhow, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can take the time to explain to me that statement, specifically when the conditional logic returns true.

I hope this question makes sense and that its not a repeat. If it is, I will greatly appreciate any links to existing answers.

Thanks!

```
function myFunc(){

var source = [
    ["CAR", "CAH", 394],
    ["CAR", "CAH", 96],
    ["CAR", "CAP", 268],
    ["DOR", "CAF", 71],
    ["DOR", "CAP", 96],
    ["DOR", "CAP", 268],
    ["VAC", "GILAB", 71]
];

var last;
var folded = source.reduce(function(prev,curr, index){

    if (last) {
        if (last[0] === curr[0] && last[1] === curr[1]) {
            last[2] += curr[2];               
            return prev;
        }
    }
    last = curr;
    prev.push(curr);

    return prev;
},[]);


};

myFunc();
```

Comment: Could you please post the link from where you found the above codes as well

Comment: Is he above code working properly?

Comment: The code is working properly. You will see the result if you add "console.log(folded);" right after the reduce function -- after the "},[]);" but before the "};". Also, I would love to give the link to the original forum I found it in but I am having trouble finding it at this moment. I will update once I find it.

Comment: when i did `console.log(myFunc());` i got undefined or nil. Not able to remember which but that was the output. Hence i asked

Answer (score 0):

**First** run inside the reduce function with the initial state as:

```
prev = []
current = ["CAR", "CAH", 394]
last = undefined
```

- `last` is undefined so we skip over the entire if statement
- `last` is now a reference to `curr`
- Then we push `curr` onto `prev`, which at first is empty: 
  `[].push(["CAR", "CAH", 394])`

**Second** run inside the reduce function with the initial state as:

```
  prev = [["CAR", "CAH", 394]]
  current = ["CAR", "CAH", 96]
  last = ["CAR", "CAH", 394]
```

- Recall that `last` is actually a reference to the *previous* `curr`,
  which has now been pushed onto the 0th element of prev.
  You can confirm this by doing: `last === prev[0]` which should evaluate true
- We now test `last[0] === curr[0] && last[1] === curr[1]`, which is `"CAR" === "CAR" && "CAH" === "CAH"`. This evaluates to true
- `last[2] += curr[2]` evaluated is `394 += 96`, which is 490
- Due to `last` and `prev[0]` being linked together by reference, we are also changing `prev[0]` when we change `last`.
- `prev` is now `[["CAR", "CAH", 490]]`
- We then hit `return prev` here, which skips over the rest of the reduce block.

**Third** run inside the reduce function with the initial state as:

```
  prev = [["CAR", "CAH", 490]]
  current = ["CAR", "CAP", 268]
  last = ["CAR", "CAH", 490]
```

- This time, testing `last[0] === curr[0] && last[1] === curr[1]` becomes false because: `"CAR" === "CAR" && "CAH" === "CAP"`
- So we establish a new `last` by reference `last` with the new `curr` (`["CAR", "CAP", 268]`)

  Essentially, this third run inside the reduce function is like the first reduce run except we're establishing a new `last` to test

The way this reduce function is written, the array you reduce must already be pre-sorted.